# tk destroy() and grid_forget() don't always work

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

i'm hoping anyone can help me out here. i'm having an issue with a tkinter gui i built. the issue only happens in windows. My GUI creates a results frame with some labels in it, when it's time to calculate something else, the user clicks on the "newPort" button and that button is supposed to remove the results frame and set to `False` some instance attributes internal to the calculation. The issue i'm having, which is apparent only in windows is that sometimes the results `frame`, and its descendant `labels` don't disappear every time. Sometimes they do, sometimes they don't. The instance variable is correctly set to `False` but the widgets are still visible on the main GUI. The GUI also contains a couple `checkboxes` and `radiobuttons` but they don't impact the creation of the results frame nor its expected destruction. I have not been able to pin point a pattern of actions the user takes before clicking on the `newPort` button which causes the `frame` and `labels` to not get destroyed. This happens when i freeze my app with py2exe, as well as running the app from the python interpreter within the eclipse IDE. I have not tried running the app from the python interpreter directly (i.e. without the IDE) and this problem does not happen on my Mac when i run the app using the eclipse python interpreter. Thanks very much all! My code looks like this:

```
import Tkinter as TK
class widget(object):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        self.parent = TK.Frame(parent)
        self.parent.grid()
        self.frame = TK.Frame(self.parent)
        self.frame.grid()
        newLedger = TK.Button(self.parent,command=self.newPort).grid()
        self.calcButton = TK.Button(self.frame,command=self.showResults)
        self.calcButton.grid()
        self.calcVariable = True
    def newPort(self):
        self.calcVariable = False
        try:
            self.second.grid_forget()
            self.first.grid_forget()
            self.resultsFrame.grid_forget()
            self.second.destroy()
            self.first.destroy()
            self.resultsFrame.destroy()
        except:
            raise
        self.frame.update_idletasks()
    def showResults(self):
        self.resultsFrame = TK.Frame(self.frame)
        self.resultsFrame.grid()
        self.first = TK.Label(self.resultsFrame,text='first')
        self.first.grid()
        self.second = TK.Label(self.resultsFrame,text='second')
        self.second.grid()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = TK.Tk()
    obj = widget(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to destroy or call `grid_forget` on the labels, and you don't need to call `grid_forget` on the resultsFrame; when you destroy the resultsFrame it will cause all off its children to be destroyed, and when these widgets are destroyed they will no longer be managed by grid.

The only way I can get widgets to not be destroyed is if I click on the "calc" button twice in a row without clicking on the "new" button in-between. I'm doing this by running your program from the command line.

Comment: thanks Bryan.Your last comment was very helpful to realize why this issue is occurring based on the pattern you identified. The showResults method is creating the widgets on-demand thus when you click the "calc" button, technically it creates a new set of widgets which are associated with the instance variable reference, as such, the widgets that remain visible no longer have a reference attached to them and hence they are not destroyed with the "new" call. To address this, i'm thinking about separating the creation of new widgets into a separate method call. other suggestions are very welcome

Comment: didn't get to complete the proposal given comments size limitation... thinking of separating the creation of the "results" frame and labels into another method call and adding logic to check against the existence of these widgets (in the case where the "calc" button is pressed twice in a row without clicking in the "new" button in between) so that they are not re-created when the calc button is pressed. maybe a separate method wouldn't be needed... another angle would be to destroy the widgets in the showResults method **before** they are created thus guaranteeing they are always fresh widgets